# clean screen from previous output in a loop in python

Tags: python, loops, screen

I have a for loop that iterate through the rows of dataframe containing some texts and shows the user texts associated with specific indices. The users should provide some labels to the text in each iteration of the loop.

As some of the texts presented to the users are long, before going to the next text, I want to clear screen such that each text is shown individually on the screen. I was doing some tests with the code below which simulates my problem, but I did not get the expected result:

```
import os
from time import sleep

list_texts=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']

for i in list_texts:
  print(i)
  l=input('Please, enter labels here: ')
  sleep(2)
  clear()
  u=input('Continue? y/n: ')
  if u == 'y':
    continue
  else:
    print('See you later')
    break
```

My desired output is the text a + the question 'Please, enter labels here: ' without the previous output. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear terminal in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so just to make sure I understood the question correctly, please correct me if I'm wrong:

*The desired output per iteration in the example is the next piece of text followed by `Please, enter labels here` on the screen without anything else from the previous iterations.*

We can do something like this:

```
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":

   
    list_texts=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']

    for i in list_texts:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print(i)
        l=input('Please, enter labels here: ')
        u=input('Continue? y/n: ')

        if u == 'n':
            print('See you later')
            break
```

Output:

```
a
Please, enter labels here: test
Continue? y/n: y
```

Followed by:

```
b
Please, enter labels here:
```

And so on for each iteration.

The line  `os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')`  empties the terminal screen at the beginning of every iteration by running cls if you're using a Windows machine and clear if you're using a Unix based one.

The post [Clear terminal in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python) is a good reference for these types of terminal manipulations (commented earlier by @Adam).

EDIT: Specifically because the environment desired is google colab, this appears to work better on that setup:

```
from google.colab import output
 
if __name__ == "__main__":

   
    list_texts=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']

    for i in list_texts:
        output.clear()
        print(i)
        l=input('Please, enter labels here: ')
        u=input('Continue? y/n: ')

        if u == 'n':
            print('See you later')
            break
```

This post specifically is good for for further information: [How to clear the output in Google Colab via code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60127913/how-to-clear-the-output-in-google-colab-via-code)

Comment: Hi, appreciate your help, but when I run your code the previous text output does not disappear from my screen. I see all texts for each interaction on my screen. So, the problem continues...

Comment: Huh interesting it works fine on my end, I tried it on Windows with the command prompt, what configuration/setup are you using?

Comment: I'm running on google colab and I also tried on pycharm

Comment: Added solution specifically for google colab above